# do we need write try catch when we want get data from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

I have developed many APIs in Laravel and I want to know for example if I want to have a list of posts in my /api/posts route I should write codes in try catch block or it does not needed?

Comment: You don't *need* them, but if you want to catch and handle specific cases when an error does arise, then you may use them.

Comment: I think you dont need to write all codes inside try catch. but if you think you dont have unstable database connection its better to do that

Answer (score 0):

The Eloquent ORM and the DB facade generally don't raise exceptions, so in most cases, you don't need to use Try/Catch blocks when performing normal queries. If you are going to use any other library or elements in your queries where you are expecting exceptions to be raised, you should use Try/Catch blocks.

For example, querying the database for posts will either return a collection of models if the criteria meet, or it will not return any results if criteria don't meet. No exceptions will be raised for your queries. So in such a scenario, using Try/Catch blocks will not make any differnce. Chances are that your code will never hit the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is that you work with transactions and try catch hand, for example:

```
use DB;

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        // your code, wherever you want

        DB::commit(); // commit if everything is ok.

        return $somethin; //return the data.

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        \Log::error($th);
        DB::rollBack(); // do a rollback in your db.
        return $this->sendError($th->getMessage(), 500); //send custom error or anything
    }
```

for more info, [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions).